# Relative import 'six.moves.urllib', should be 'six.moves'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint, pylintrc

I am facing this situation in pylint 1.9.3

My code `exp.py` contains only this line

`from six.moves.urllib import parse as urllib`

when i run `pylint exp.py` then im getting this error

> [W0403(relative-import), ] Relative import 'six.moves.urllib', should be 'six.moves'

Any idea on how to fix this??

any help would be of great use..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try importing it as `from six.moves import urllib.parse as urllib`

Comment: invalid syntax @UpasanaMittal

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

You are suffering a [known issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2180) of pylint.